# Java 8 Stream exception handling while adding objects from function return value to list

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-stream

I'm having a hard time understanding how to handle exceptions when using a Java 8 stream. I would like to add objects to an empty list, and each object gets returned from a function that can potentially throw an exception depending on what the input is. If an exception is thrown for only certain values on the input list, I want it to continue to loop through the remainder of the input list. It seems easy to do with a for loop:

```
  List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Input> inputs = getInputs(); //returns a list of inputs
  int exceptionCount = 0;

   // If an exception is thrown
   for (Input input : inputs){
        try {
           itemList.add(getItem(input));
        } catch (Exception e ) {
         // handle exception from getItem(input)
          exceptionCount = exceptionCount + 1;
        }  
   }
```

It seems like it may be possible to achieve this with a Java stream, but I'm not quite sure how to handle the exception that could be thrown by the `getItem()` function.
Here's what I have so far:

```
    final List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

     try {
         itemList = getInputs().stream()
                          .map(this::getItem)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
     } catch (Exception e ) {
         // handle exception from getItem(input)
          exceptionCount = exceptionCount + 1;
        }
```

The above obviously won't work because as soon as there is *one* exception thrown from `getItem`, the loop will not continue and only one exception will be thrown for the entire stream. Is there any way I can achieve the same implementation as my basic for loop with Java 8 streams?

Comment: Out of interest... why do you insist on using a `Stream`?

Comment: Yes you can by implementing BaseStream and Iterator and wrapping it all up yourself; however, it cannot be done efficiently because Java does not have coroutines.

Comment: Yes. Streams break even around 10K items. So unless you are dealing with these sizes, there is no point in using them

Comment: @efekctive - I thought it was lambdas that break even at 10k.  Same difference though, though of course you can use a stream without lambdas.

Comment: Earlier this year a couple of SO members posted two really well researched posts and reached similar conclusions. Lambdas do no have a "size" as far as I know. It is the stream that handles them that carries the load. Around the February/March time frame

Comment: @efekctive do you have a link? that sounds really interesting!

Comment: you could extract the logic you trying to do in the stream into a separate method and in that method deal with the try/catch and exceptions.

Comment: let me browse...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375003/why-lambda-intstream-anymatch-is-10-slower-than-naive-implementation#comment71904012_42375003 This is one of them. The other was posted shortly after

Comment: Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616583/how-to-map-runtimeexceptions-in-java-streams-to-recover-from-invalid-stream-el/44620143

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should catch the exception within the `map` operation:

```
class ExceptionCounter {
    private int count = 0;

    void inc() { count++; }

    int getCount() { return count; }
}

ExceptionCounter counter = new ExceptionCounter();

List<Item> items = getInputs().stream()
    .map(input -> {
        try {
            return getItem(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
            counter.inc();
        }
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

While this works as expected for sequential streams, it won't work for parallel streams. Even if the stream is not parallel, we still need the `ExceptionCounter` holder class because variables referenced from within arguments of stream operations (such as `map`) must be *effectively final*. (You can use an array of one element or an `AtomicInteger` instead of a holder class).

If we add `synchronized` to the `inc` method of `ExceptionCounter` class, then the solution above would support parallel streams. However, there would be a lot of thread contention on the `inc` method's lock, thus losing the advantages of parallelization. This (along with attempting to not create error-prone code) is the reason why *side-effects* are discouraged on streams. And counting the number of exceptions is in fact a side-effect.

For this particular case, you can avoid the side effect if you use a custom collector:

```
class Result<R> {
    List<R> values = new ArrayList<>();
    int exceptionCount = 0;
    // TODO getters
}

static <T, R> Result<R> mappingToListCountingExceptions(Function<T, R> mapper) {
    class Acc {
        Result<R> result = new Result<>();

        void add(T t) {
            try {
                R res = mapper.apply(t);
                result.value.add(res);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result.exceptionCount++;
            }
        }

        Acc merge(Acc another) {
            result.values.addAll(another.values);
            result.exceptionCount += another.exceptionCount;
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, acc -> acc.result);
}
```

You can use this custom collector as follows:

```
Result<Item> items = getInputs().stream()
    .collect(mappingToListCountingExceptions(this::getItem));
```

Now it's up to you to decide whether this approach is better than a traditional `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Event there are several ways to handle exceptions in the stream:

1. to catch the exception in the map

```
files.stream()
   .parallel()
   .map(file-> {
       try {
           return file.getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       }
   })
   .forEach(inputStream -> carService.saveCars(inputStream));
```

---

2. to extract the function argument to map into a method of its own:

```
files.stream()
      .parallel()
      .map(file-> extractInputStream(file))
      .forEach(inputStream -> carService.saveCars(inputStream));
```

and

```
  private InputStream extractInputStream(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            return file.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

---

3. create another functional interface, similar to Function, whose apply method did declare that it throws an exception:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface FunctionWithException<T, R, E extends Exception> {
  R apply(T t) throws E;
}
```

and

```
private <T, R, E extends Exception>
    Function<T, R> wrapper(FunctionWithException<T, R, E> fun) {
        return arg -> {
                        try {
                            return fun.apply(arg);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
        };
}
```

then use it like this

```
files.stream()
     .parallel()
     .map(wrapper(file->file.getInputStream()))
     .forEach(inputStream -> carService.saveCars(inputStream));
```

---

4. But if you want to do efficiently with all Functional interfaces, I suggest using this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pivovarit</groupId>
    <artifactId>throwing-function</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

All explained with an example in this post [Java 8, How to handle exceptions in a stream?](https://medium.com/@makhlouf.raouf/java-8-how-to-handle-exceptions-in-a-stream-f884172b10)

Answer (score 0):

Try vavr library. It takes java functional programming to ++ level.